# How I increase the space between icon and the app border?

Tags: android

In a Activity that extends of ActionBarActivity I use `supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);` and `setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);` to show that mini-progress dialog as actionbar item menu.

How I can separate more to the screen?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do not know how you implements that tiny progress bar but... as far as I know you need to create a customview for this, right? something like this: create a new Class like RefreshMenuItemHelper:

```
public class RefreshMenuItemHelper {
    private WeakReference<MenuItem> item;

    /**
     * Set the menu item.
     * @param item
     */
    public void setMenuItem(MenuItem item) {
        this.item = new WeakReference<MenuItem>(item);
    }

    /**
     * Show the indeterminate progress.
     */
    public void showLoading() {
        if(item != null) {
            item.get().setActionView(R.layout.menu_item_action_refresh);
            item.get().expandActionView();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Stop and dismiss the indeterminate progress.
     */
    public void stopLoading() {
        item.get().collapseActionView();
        item.get().setActionView(null);
    }

}
```

The menu_item_action_refresh is just a simple layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="56dp">
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

And finally in yours:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_refresh:
                refreshHelper.setMenuItem(item);
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Now you can use showLoading() and stopLoading() to start or stop the indeterminate progress. Also make sure the menu.xml has the ic_refresh.png in R.id.action_refresh.

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thanks @nicolas-jafelle! I will try this solution and comment the results. The tiny progress dialog is a menu that android provides with supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS); and setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(boolean)

Comment: please add some code related of refreshHelper variable. I want to use but null pointer. thanks! I create the class and I set the menu item but the use of showLoading() do not depend if the users click the item in the menu

Comment: in your oncreate() create a new instance of RefreshMenuItemHelper, like:
RefreshMenuItemHelper helper = new RefreshMenuItemHelper();